# DataContract and KnownTypes for Inherited classes using Service Bus 1.0

Tags: .net, datacontractserializer, datacontract, servicebus, known-types

Hi I have the following class hierarchy:

```
public class SuperJob{
}

public class JobA:SuperJob{
}

public class JobB:SuperJob{
}
```

When i try to deserialise a SuperJob i get

```
Expecting element 'SuperJob' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/...'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'JobA', namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/...'.
```

I have annotated my classes as follows:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(JobA))]
[KnownType(typeof(JobB))]
public class SuperJob{
}

[DataContract]
public class JobA:SuperJob{
}

[DataContract]
public class JobB:SuperJob{
}
```

Not sure what i am doing wrong? Any ideas how do i fix this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Please post your deserialization code.

Comment: ...And serialization code too.

Comment: To deserialize i am using a windows service bus 1.0 so its using that method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh144211.aspx To serialise i am just putting an object on the que using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queueclient.send.aspx

Comment: Is this a WCF service?  If so, can you post your service contract?

Comment: Oh, and what does the XML look like?

Comment: its a buffered stream so can't get to the xml...

Comment: hmm reading up on this more, it looks like it could be the way the brokered message instantiates the deseralizer.. as based on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177555/datacontractserializer-knowntype-and-inheritance?rq=1 if the deseralizer is created using .getType() the resulting xml is incorrect... any thoughts?

Comment: In general, yes, you need to serialize and deserialize using a serializer built with the base type. I'm not familiar with the service bus, but I suspect that is what's happening. You need a (de)serializer created with `typeof(SuperJob)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix this issue, there is a bug in the way the service bus instantiates the serialiser. looks like internally it instantiates the serialiser with JobA.getType(). So  the best way forward is to create your own DataSerializer object which uses typeOf(JobA) and pass that in both when sending the message on to the bus and reading off the bus.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ServiceKnownType] attribute on your service :

```
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(JobA))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(JobB))]
public interface IJobService 
{
.... methods
}

Another approach would be to pass knowntypes in DataContractSerializer constructor.

List<Type> knownTypeList = new List<Type>();
knownTypeList.Add(typeof(JobA));
knownTypeList.Add(typeof(JobB));

// Create a DatatContractSerializer with the collection.
DataContractSerializer ser2 = new DataContractSerializer(
                                  typeof(SuperJob), knownTypeList);
```